# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError "undefined method `translates'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, globalize3

I have an application in local that works great, but when I push on server it crash with this error:

```
`NoMethodError in PagesController#index

undefined method `translates' for #<Class:0x0000000339e880>`
```

It may be caused by the globalize3 gem, but I installed some gems that i found in other questions and doesn't resolve my problem.
I installed:

```
- gem 'globalize', '~> 3.1.0' 
- gem 'globalize-accessors'
- gem 'globalize3_helpers'
- gem "friendly_id"
- gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6.1'
- gem 'batch_translations', '~> 0.1.3'
```

This is my gemfile in my server:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'pg'
gem 'json'
gem 'acts_as_list'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'globalize3', '0.2.0.beta8'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'rabl'

gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'awesome_nested_set' # or any similar gem (gem 'nested_set')
gem "the_sortable_tree", "~> 2.5.0"

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'browser'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'debugger'
  gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
  gem 'yard'
  gem 'redcarpet'
end  

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "spork"
  gem "guard-spork"
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
  gem 'poltergeist'
end
```

And this is my gemfile in my server:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'pg', '=0.14.1' 
gem 'json'
gem 'acts_as_list'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem 'globalize3'
gem 'globalize3_helpers'
gem "friendly_id"
gem 'i18n', '~> 0.6.1'
gem 'batch_translations', '~> 0.1.3' 
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'rabl'

gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
gem "the_sortable_tree", "~> 2.5.0"

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

gem 'will_paginate'

gem 'browser'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'


group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  #gem 'capistrano-unicorn'
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0"
  gem 'yard'
  #gem 'redcarpet'
end  

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9.1'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem "spork"
  gem "guard-spork"
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'
  gem 'poltergeist'
end
```

My gem list on local server:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
actionpack (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
actionview (4.1.8, 4.1.6)
activemodel (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
activerecord (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
activerecord-postgres-hstore (0.5.3)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
activesupport (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
acts_as_list (0.5.0, 0.1.8)
addressable (2.3.6, 2.3.2)
annotate (2.6.5, 2.5.0)
apartment (0.25.2)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3, 3.0.2)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
autoprefixer-rails (4.0.1.1)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.6, 2.1.4)
awesome_print (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
barby (0.5.0)
batch_translations (0.1.3)
bcrypt (3.1.9)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
best_in_place (2.0.2)
better_errors (2.0.0, 0.3.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
bootstrap-sass (3.3.1.0)
browser (0.8.0, 0.1.5)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4, 3.0.3)
bundler (1.7.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
cancan (1.6.8)
capistrano (2.15.5, 2.13.5)
capybara (2.4.4)
carrierwave (0.10.0, 0.7.1)
celluloid (0.16.0)
childprocess (0.5.5)
choice (0.1.6)
cliver (0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.0, 1.0.7)
coffee-rails (4.1.0, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.8.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.3)
columnize (0.9.0, 0.8.9)
database_cleaner (1.3.0)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger (1.6.8)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.7)
devise (3.4.1)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
exception_notification (3.0.1)
execjs (2.2.2, 1.4.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
factory_girl (4.5.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
faker (1.4.3)
faraday (0.8.4)
ffi (1.9.6)
formatador (0.2.5)
friendly_id (4.0.10.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.5)
globalize (3.1.0)
globalize-accessors (0.1.5)
globalize3 (0.2.0.beta8)
globalize3_helpers (0.3.0)
guard (2.10.4, 2.9.0, 2.8.2, 1.8.3)
guard-compat (1.1.0, 0.3.0)
guard-rspec (4.5.0, 4.4.2, 4.3.1, 3.1.0)
guard-spork (2.1.0, 2.0.2, 2.0.1, 1.5.2)
haml (4.1.0.beta.1, 4.0.6)
haml-rails (0.6.0, 0.4)
hashery (2.1.0)
highline (1.6.21, 1.6.16, 1.6.15)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
hitimes (1.2.2)
hpricot (0.8.6)
html2haml (1.0.1)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.7.0.beta1, 0.6.11, 0.6.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-datatables-rails (2.2.2)
jquery-migrate-rails (1.2.1)
jquery-rails (3.1.2, 2.3.0, 2.1.4, 2.1.2)
jquery-ui-rails (5.0.3, 4.1.2, 2.0.2)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.5)
kgio (2.9.2, 2.7.4)
launchy (2.4.3)
listen (2.8.3, 2.8.2, 2.8.1, 1.3.1)
lumberjack (1.0.9)
mail (2.6.3, 2.6.1, 2.5.4, 2.4.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (2.4.3, 2.3, 1.25.1, 1.23, 1.19)
mini_portile (0.6.1)
minitest (5.5.0, 5.4.2, 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.10.1, 1.7.7, 1.4.0, 1.3.6)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
nenv (0.1.1)
nestedsortabletree-rails (0.1.2.1)
net-scp (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.9.1, 2.6.6, 2.6.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.6.5, 1.6.4.1)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.6.1)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
paper_trail (2.7.2)
pdf-reader (1.2.0)
pg (0.17.1, 0.14.1)
poltergeist (1.5.1)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.3)
prawn (0.12.0)
prawn-svg (0.12.0.3)
pry (0.10.1)
pry-rails (0.3.2)
psych (2.0.3)
quiet_assets (1.0.3)
rabl (0.11.5, 0.11.4)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
rails-api (0.3.1, 0.0.3, 0.0.2)
rails-erd (1.1.0)
railties (4.1.8, 4.1.6, 3.2.13, 3.2.8, 3.2.2)
raindrops (0.13.0, 0.10.0)
rake (10.4.2, 10.4.0, 10.3.2, 10.1.0, 10.0.4, 10.0.2, 0.9.2.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rb-kqueue (0.2.3)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (4.1.0, 3.12.2, 3.12)
redactor-rails (0.4.5)
redcarpet (3.2.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.0)
remotipart (1.2.1)
responders (1.1.2)
rmagick (2.13.4, 2.13.3, 2.13.1)
rspec (3.1.0, 2.99.0)
rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
rspec-core (3.1.7, 2.99.2)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2, 2.99.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3, 2.99.2)
rspec-rails (3.1.0, 2.99.0)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
ruby-graphviz (1.0.9)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
ruby_parser (3.1.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.1.6)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sass (3.4.9, 3.4.8, 3.2.3, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (5.0.0, 3.2.6, 3.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (2.44.0)
sexp_processor (4.4.4)
slop (3.6.0)
sorcery (0.7.13)
spork (0.9.2)
sprockets (2.12.3, 2.12.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.1.4, 2.1.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.2, 2.1.4)
sqlite3 (1.3.10)
state_machine (1.1.2)
superfish-rails (1.6.0.1)
terminal-notifier-guard (1.6.4)
test-unit (2.1.1.0)
the_sortable_tree (2.5.0)
thor (0.19.1, 0.16.0, 0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
timers (4.0.1)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.14, 1.4.12, 1.4.10)
ttfunk (1.0.3)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.42, 0.3.37, 0.3.35, 0.3.33)
uglifier (2.6.0, 2.5.3, 1.3.0)
unicorn (4.4.0)
warden (1.2.3)
websocket (1.2.1)
websocket-driver (0.5.0, 0.4.0)
websocket-extensions (0.1.1)
will_paginate (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
xpath (2.0.0)
yard (0.8.7.6)
```

And my Gem list on server:

```
actionmailer (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
actionpack (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
actionview (4.1.0)
activemodel (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
activerecord (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
activerecord-postgres-hstore (0.5.3)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.8)
activesupport (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
acts_as_list (0.5.0)
addressable (2.3.6, 2.3.2)
annotate (2.6.5)
arel (5.0.1.20140414130214, 3.0.3, 3.0.2)
Ascii85 (1.0.2)
autoprefixer-rails (4.0.1.1)
awesome_nested_set (2.1.6, 2.1.4)
awesome_print (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
barby (0.5.0)
batch_translations (0.1.3)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
best_in_place (2.0.2)
better_errors (2.0.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
browser (0.8.0, 0.1.5)
builder (3.2.2, 3.0.4)
bullet (4.2.0)
bundler (1.6.2)
cancan (1.6.8)
capistrano (2.15.5, 2.13.5)
capybara (2.4.4, 2.0.1)
carrierwave (0.10.0, 0.7.1)
celluloid (0.16.0)
childprocess (0.5.5, 0.3.6)
choice (0.1.6)
cliver (0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.0, 1.0.8)
coffee-rails (4.0.1, 3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.8.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.4.0, 1.3.3)
columnize (0.9.0, 0.8.9)
daemon_controller (1.2.0)
database_cleaner (0.9.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
debugger (1.6.8)
debugger-linecache (1.2.0)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.3.7)
diff-lcs (1.2.5)
erubis (2.7.0)
exception_notification (3.0.1)
execjs (2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.5.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
faraday (0.8.4)
ffi (1.9.6, 1.2.0)
formatador (0.2.5)
friendly_id (4.0.10.1)
globalize (3.1.0)
globalize-accessors (0.1.5)
globalize3 (0.3.1, 0.2.0.beta8)
globalize3_helpers (0.3.0)
guard (2.10.4, 2.9.0, 1.5.4)
guard-compat (1.1.0)
guard-rspec (4.5.0, 4.3.1)
guard-spork (2.1.0, 2.0.2)
guard-test (0.7.0)
haml (4.0.6)
haml-rails (0.4)
hashery (2.1.0)
highline (1.6.21, 1.6.16, 1.6.15)
hike (1.2.3, 1.2.1)
hitimes (1.2.2)
httpauth (0.2.0)
i18n (0.6.11, 0.6.9, 0.6.1)
io-console (0.4.2)
jbuilder (2.2.5, 2.2.4, 2.2.3, 2.2.2, 2.2.0, 2.1.3, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-migrate-rails (1.2.1)
jquery-rails (3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 2.1.4)
jquery-ui-rails (4.1.2, 2.0.2)
json (1.8.1, 1.7.5)
kgio (2.9.2, 2.7.4, 2.0.0)
launchy (2.4.3, 2.1.2)
letter_opener (1.0.0)
libwebsocket (0.1.7.1)
listen (2.8.4, 2.8.3, 0.6.0)
lumberjack (1.0.9, 1.0.2)
mail (2.5.4, 2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
method_source (0.8.2, 0.8.1)
mime-types (1.25.1, 1.19)
mini_portile (0.6.1)
minitest (5.4.3, 5.4.2, 5.4.1, 5.4.0, 5.3.5, 5.3.4, 5.3.3, 4.7.5)
mocha (0.13.1)
multi_json (1.10.1, 1.9.3, 1.4.0)
multipart-post (1.1.5)
nenv (0.1.1)
net-scp (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.9.1, 2.6.6, 2.6.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.6.5, 1.5.5)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.6.1)
paper_trail (2.7.2)
passenger (4.0.41)
pdf-reader (1.2.0)
pg (0.17.1, 0.14.1)
poltergeist (1.5.1)
polyglot (0.3.5, 0.3.4, 0.3.3)
prawn (0.12.0)
prawn-svg (0.12.0.3)
pry (0.10.1, 0.9.10)
pry-rails (0.3.2, 0.2.2)
psych (2.0.3)
rabl (0.11.5, 0.11.4)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.4, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
rails-api (0.3.1)
rails-erd (1.2.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.0)
railties (4.1.0, 3.2.13, 3.2.8)
raindrops (0.13.0, 0.10.0)
rake (10.4.2, 10.3.2, 10.1.0, 10.0.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4, 0.9.2)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rb-readline (0.4.2)
rdoc (4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 3.12.2, 3.12)
redcarpet (3.2.2, 3.2.1)
remotipart (1.2.1)
rspec (3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.7)
rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
rspec-rails (3.1.0)
rspec-support (3.1.2)
ruby-graphviz (1.0.9, 1.0.8)
ruby-rc4 (0.1.5)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.4.9, 3.2.19, 3.2.3, 3.2.1)
sass-rails (4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 3.2.6, 3.2.5)
sdoc (0.4.1, 0.4.0)
selenium-webdriver (2.27.0)
slop (3.6.0, 3.3.3)
sorcery (0.7.13)
spork (0.9.2)
spring (1.2.0, 1.1.3)
sprockets (2.12.3, 2.12.1, 2.11.3, 2.11.0, 2.2.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.3)
sprockets-rails (2.2.2, 2.2.0, 2.1.4, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.10, 1.3.9)
state_machine (1.1.2)
superfish-rails (1.6.0.1)
terminal-notifier-guard (1.6.4)
test-unit (2.5.3, 2.1.1.0)
the_sortable_tree (2.5.0, 1.9.4)
thor (0.19.1, 0.16.0)
thread_safe (0.3.4, 0.3.3)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
timers (4.0.1)
treetop (1.4.15, 1.4.12)
ttfunk (1.0.3)
turbolinks (2.5.2, 2.5.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.0, 2.2.2)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.1.0, 0.3.42, 0.3.35)
uglifier (2.6.0, 2.5.3, 2.5.1, 1.3.0)
unicorn (4.4.0)
uniform_notifier (1.1.0)
websocket (1.0.4)
websocket-driver (0.5.1, 0.5.0, 0.4.0)
websocket-extensions (0.1.1)
will_paginate (3.0.7, 3.0.3)
xpath (2.0.0, 1.0.0)
yard (0.8.7.6, 0.8.3)
```

Maybe one gem or some configuration in application.rb?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried freezing the globalize3 gem version on your server, like you have locally? gem 'globalize3', '0.2.0.beta8'

Comment: Why do you have different gemfiles for your local and server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Gemfile` is designed to be the same in all envs, and then load different gems based on the env by using groups like you do on `group :development ...`. That said, you are possibly using different versions of the gem in both envs.

Looking at the difference between both versions, 0.2.0.beta8 and 0.3.1, you can see `translates` is still there, but maybe the setup that adds it has changed https://github.com/globalize/globalize/compare/v0.2.0.beta8...v0.3.1#diff-a4e451ff8babf2969ff95b0205af6dd1L4

Try fixing the version on your server Gemfile (though you really should have the same file in both prod and dev)

Comment: Thanks! The gem 'globalize3 0.3.1' was in server, I change to old version on gemfile, then 'bundle update globalize3' and now works!